# Failed to download data from Yahoo finance using Quantmod

Tags: r, time-series, quantmod

I was trying to download data from `Yahoo finance` using `Quantmod` package as below, but failed to get any data.

```
library(quantmod)
> get(getSymbols("^FTSE"))
Error in get(getSymbols("^FTSE")) : object '^FTSE' not found
In addition: Warning message:
^FTSE contains missing values. Some functions will not work if objects contain missing values in the middle of the series. Consider using na.omit(), na.approx(), na.fill(), etc to remove or replace them.
```

Any idea why it is failing would be highly appreciated.

**Below is my session information**

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C           LC_TIME=C.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=C.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C              LC_ADDRESS=C          
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C         LC_MEASUREMENT=C.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C   

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] quantmod_0.4-14 TTR_0.23-4      xts_0.11-2      zoo_1.8-5      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.0  tools_3.6.0     curl_3.3        grid_3.6.0     
[5] lattice_0.20-38
```

Comment: Why are you using `get()` around the `getSymbols()`? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: use alphavantage api instead, yahoo finance is no longer maintained

Comment: @JaredMarks: Yahoo Finance is maintained, but the data quality is worse than it has been in the past, so I don't recommend using them. Maybe you're thinking of Google Finance (they no longer provide data)? I recommend either [Tiingo](https://api.tiingo.com/) or [Alpha Vantage](https://www.alphavantage.co/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getSymbol()` loads the object in the environment, so to access it you would just call the object name directly.

```r
> library(quantmod)
> getSymbols("^FTSE") 
> FTSE
           FTSE.Open FTSE.High FTSE.Low FTSE.Close FTSE.Volume FTSE.Adjusted
2007-01-02    6220.8    6312.5   6220.8     6310.9  1074946500        6310.9
2007-01-03    6310.9    6322.0   6296.0     6319.0  1606892700        6319.0
```

Alternatively, you can use `get()`, but `get()` requires the object name to be quoted.

```r
> library(quantmod)
> getSymbols("^FTSE")
> get("FTSE")
           FTSE.Open FTSE.High FTSE.Low FTSE.Close FTSE.Volume FTSE.Adjusted
2007-01-02    6220.8    6312.5   6220.8     6310.9  1074946500        6310.9
2007-01-03    6310.9    6322.0   6296.0     6319.0  1606892700        6319.0
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend setting the `auto.assign` argument to `FALSE`. Then you can assign the output of `getSymbols()` to whatever object you want.  For example:

```
ftse <- getSymbols("^FTSE", auto.assign = FALSE)
head(ftse)
#            FTSE.Open FTSE.High FTSE.Low FTSE.Close FTSE.Volume FTSE.Adjusted
# 2007-01-02    6220.8    6312.5   6220.8     6310.9  1074946500        6310.9
# 2007-01-03    6310.9    6322.0   6296.0     6319.0  1606892700        6319.0
# 2007-01-04    6319.0    6319.0   6261.0     6287.0  1902875500        6287.0
# 2007-01-05    6287.0    6287.0   6220.1     6220.1  1622439300        6220.1
# 2007-01-08    6220.1    6246.0   6187.0     6194.2  1326700900        6194.2
# 2007-01-09    6194.2    6218.5   6190.4     6196.1  2143699600        6196.1
```